# Android - onBackPressed to turn off app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

hope you are having a great day!

So today I've got a rather simple question. In my main activity when I press the back button I want the application I've developed to turn off no matter what it did right before. And delete the stacks so it opens up fresh the next time.

**The activities work like this:**

**A (Main Menu)**

There are 4 buttons here, leading to 4 different activities **B (About)**, **C (Change Theme)**, **D (Calculate BMI with US Measurements)**, **E (Calculate BMI with EU Measurements)**

D and E both lead to **F (Results)**.

When I am in F and press back I want to get back to the previous (D or E) - which is fixed and it keeps the last typed in information for convenience.

On the F activity there's a button to go straight back to the menu. And if I press this button **and then** the standard android back button I will get from A to D/E and then to A again before closing out the application.

When I am in B, C, D, E I want to go back to A.
When I am in A I want to turn off the application.

The settings for each one of them is:

```
A - onBackPressed() - Here I want to put to turn off the application. 
onClickA/B/C/D()
{ 
    Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(Intent);
    finish();
}

B - android:noHistory(true)
onBackPressed()
{ 
    Start New Intent A.
}

C - android:noHistory(true)
onBackPressed()
{
    Start New Intent A (so the changes take effect on the Main Menu even if you press back).
}

D - onBackPressed()
{
    Start New Intent A
    finish();
}

E - onBackPressed()
{
    Start New Intent A
    finish();
}

F - Nothing specific.
```

Comment: Any suggested changes to make it more optimized are apprechiated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.exit(0) method onBackPress()

Comment: You should never call System.exit(0). Its more preferable to used Activity based methods to exit like finish()

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you might want to switch to fragments because what you are doing here doesn't seem so complext that an activity would be needed here.
If you switched to fragments it's easy to add those fragments to the backstack that you want to come back from.
That way you have to overwrite the onBackPressed() only once.